# How to order replication

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to order storage replication by API in soft-layer.
and I choose a data-center which is Singapore.

Below is a test code:

```
Replication storage = new Replication();
storage.setVolumeId(new Long("10312709"));
storage.setPackageId(new Long("240"));
storage.setLocation("224092");

Price price = new Price();
price.setId(new Long("145321"));
storage.getPrices().add(price);

Order.Service service = Order.service(client);
service.verifyOrder(storage);
```

but all prices are invalid.

```
45058  -> Invalid price Endurance Storage (45058) provided on the order container.
45068  -> Invalid price 0.25 IOPS per GB (45068) provided on the order container.
45108  -> Invalid price File Storage (45108) provided on the order container.    
147101 -> Invalid price 20 GB Storage Space (147101) provided on the order container.
144011 -> Invalid price 20 GB Storage Space (144011) provided on the order container.
145321 -> Invalid price 20 GB Storage Space (145321) provided on the order container.    
147099 -> The price for 20 GB Storage Space (#147099) is not valid for location sng01
```

How to know valid priceID for replciation.

If you provide a sample java code or API guide, it will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

it has been solved. 
Enterprise object is needed than Replication.
below is code :

```
Enterprise storage = new Enterprise();
storage.setPackageId(new Long("240"));
storage.setOriginVolumeId(new Long("10312709"));
storage.setOriginVolumeScheduleId(new Long("86285"));
storage.setLocation("SINGAPORE");
```

thanks.